# Отсортировать вектор по значению функции от элемента

Tags: c++, сортировка

Здравствуйте! Сейчас есть такой кусок кода:

```
vector<pair<algorithm, int>> pop;

for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    pop.push_back(make_pair(population[i], fitness(population[i], tests)));

sort(pop.begin(), pop.end(), 
    [](pair<algorithm, int> a, pair<algorithm, int> b)
    {return a.second > b.second;});

for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    population[i] = pop[i].first;
```

Он нужен для того, чтобы отсортировать массив `population` по значению функции `fitness`.

Расскажите, нет ли способа написать то же самое проще и, самое главное, быстрее?

---

`algotihm` - `vector<pair<string, string>>`
`fitness` выполняет, казалось бы, простые вычисления над строками, но, после замены

```
sort(population.begin(), population.end(), 
    [tests](algorithm a, algorithm b)
    {return fitness(a, tests) > fitness(b, tests);});
```

на первый кусок кода, стало сильно быстрее (не замерял, но, по ощущениям, на десятки секунд).

---

Замерил время исполнения программы с первым куском кода. Получается 30+-2 секунды.

## Эксперимент №1:

```
sort(pop.begin(), pop.end(), 
    [](const pair<algorithm, int>& a, const pair<algorithm, int>& b)
    {return a.second > b.second;});
```

18+-1 секунда.

## Эксперимент №2:

```
pop.reserve(100);

for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    pop.emplace_back(make_pair(population[i], fitness(population[i], tests)));
```

(первые изменения остаются)

Те же 18 секунд.

## Эксперимент №3

Заменил

```
vector<pair<algorithm, int>> pop;
```

на

```
pair<algorithm, int> pop[100];
```

Те же 18 секунд.

## Эксперимент №4

Поменял объявление `fitness` с

```
int fitness(const algorithm algo, const vector<test> tests)
```

на

```
int fitness(const algorithm& algo, const vector<test>& tests)
```

16 секунд.

## Эксперимент 4.1

Во всех объявлениях функций поменял

```
const type
```

на

```
const type&
```

13 секунд.

## Эксперимент №5

Слил два цикла: поменял

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){a}
многабуков
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){b}
```

на

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){a; b}
```

11 секунд.

Comment: Кажется, зависит от того, что находится в массиве.

Comment: Обрати внимание, `tests` в лямду надо захватывать по ссылке `[&test]`, а не по значению. Это избавит тебя от копирования объекта.

Comment: Уже просто интересно... Дайте реальный код - включая эту страшную функцию. хочется повозиться... И желательно какие-то реальные тестовые данные, чтобы потестировать.

Comment: Сейчас создам новый вопрос.

Comment: @Harry вот новый [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729203/Инспекция-кода-генетический-поиск)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - использовать функцию прямо в компараторе, если она быстро считается.

Если нет - вектор, в котором хранить значения функции не в паре с самими значениями, и потом их туда-сюда таскать, а вкупе с указателями на элементы исходного массива.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала сделайте `reserve(100)` для `pop`, используйте `emplace_back` вместо `push_back` для оптимизации вставки в вектор `pop`. Вместо `population[i] = pop[i].first;` пиши `population[i].swap(pop[i].first);`

Это ожидаемый порядок константы или может быть 1000000? Какова сложноть копирования класса  `algorithm`? Если копирование тривиальное (например, структура с POD типами и что-то типа того), а число 100-1000, то это, наверное, самое быстрое решение. У вас все данные данны лягут в L1 кеш процессора и с той скоростью ника.

Если в `algorithm` "тяжелая" для копирования, а `fitness` быстрая (например, `fitness(...) { return p.some_number * p.some_rank;}`), то лучше сортировать сразу `population`

```
auto end = population.begin()
std::advance(end, 100)
sort(population.begin(), end, 
    [&tests](const pair<algorithm, int>& a, const pair<algorithm, int>& b)
    {return fitness(a.second, tests) > (b.second, tests);});
```

### Дополнения к экспериментам

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    int f = fitness(population[i], tests);
    pop.emplace_back(make_pair(std::move(population[i]), f)); // <-- emplace
}
// ....
sort(pop.begin(), pop.end(), ...)
// ...
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    population[i].swap(pop[i].first);
```