# Инспекция кода: генетический поиск

Tags: c++, алгоритм, оптимизация, инспекция-кода, производительность

Здравствуйте! Сейчас пытаюсь искать алгоритмы Маркова с помощью генетических алгоритмов. Есть такой вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::sort;
using std::pair;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

typedef pair<string, string> rule;
typedef vector<rule> algorithm;
typedef pair<string, string> test;


void print_rule(rule r)
{
    cout<<r.first<<" -> "<<r.second<<endl;
}

void print_algorithm(algorithm algo)
{
    cout<<endl;

    for(int i=0; i<algo.size(); i++)
        print_rule(algo[i]);

    cout<<endl;
}


string apply_algorithm(string str, const algorithm& algo, bool verbose=false)
{
    vector<string> prevs;
    int step = 0;

    bool loop=false;


    bool found = false;
    for(int i=0; i<algo.size(); i++)
    {
        if(str.find(algo[i].first)!=-1)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!found)
        return str;

    while(step<10000 && !loop)
    {
        step++;

        if(str.length()>100)
            break;

        for(int i=0; i<algo.size(); i++)
        {
            if(str.find(algo[i].first) != -1)
            {
                int first = str.find(algo[i].first);
                int len   = (algo[i].first).length();
                str.replace(first, len, algo[i].second);

                if(verbose)
                {
                    cout<<"found '"<<algo[i].first<<"' -> '"<<algo[i].second<<"'"<<endl;
                    cout<<str<<endl;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<prevs.size(); i++)
        {
            if(prevs[i] == str)
            {
                loop = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        prevs.push_back(str);
    }

    return str;
}

string mutate_string(string str)
{
    int chance = rand()%100;

    if(chance<25)
    {
        char n = (char)(rand()%94+32);
        str.push_back(n);
        return str;
    }

    else if(chance<50 && str.length()>0)
    {
        str.erase(rand()%str.length(), 1);
        return str;
    }

    else if(chance<75 && str.length()>0)
    {
        auto index = str.begin()+rand()%str.length();
        str.insert(index, 1, (char)(rand()%94+32));
        return str;
    }

    return str;
}

rule mutate_rule(rule r)
{
    string left = r.first;
    string right = r.second;

    int chance = rand()%100;

    if(chance<33)
    {
        left = mutate_string(left);
    }

    else if(chance<66)
    {
        right = mutate_string(right);
    }

    else
    {
        left = mutate_string(left);
        // cout<<left<<endl;
        right = mutate_string(right);
        // cout<<right<<endl;
    }

    rule result(left, right);

    return result;
}

string random_string(const int length)
{
    string ret = "";

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        ret.push_back((char)(rand()%94+32));

    return ret;
}

rule random_rule()
{
    return make_pair(random_string(rand()%5+1),
                     random_string(rand()%5+1));
}

algorithm mutate_algoritm(algorithm algo)
{
    int chance = rand()%100;

    if(chance<33)
    {
        algo.push_back(random_rule());
        return algo;
    }

    else if(chance<66 && algo.size() > 1)
    {
        auto index = algo.begin()+rand()%algo.size();
        algo.erase(index);
        return algo;
    }

    else 
    {
        int index = rand()%algo.size();
        rule new_rule = mutate_rule(algo[index]);
        algo[index] = new_rule;
        return algo;
    }
}

algorithm random_algoritm()
{
    int length = rand()%10+1;

    algorithm ret;

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        ret.push_back(random_rule());

    return ret;
}

int max_fitness(const vector<test>& tests)
{
    int length = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<tests.size(); i++)
        length+=tests[i].second.length();

    return length;
}

int difference(const string& a, const string& b)
{
    if(a.length()!=b.length())
        return -abs(a.length()-b.length());

    int ret=0;

    for(int i=0; i<a.length(); i++)
        if(a[i] == b[i])
            ret++;

    return ret;
}

int fitness(const algorithm& algo, const vector<test>& tests)
{
    int ret = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<tests.size(); i++)
    {
        string result = apply_algorithm(tests[i].first, algo);

        ret+=difference(result, tests[i].second);
    }

    return ret;
}                      

int fitness_opt(const algorithm& algo, const vector<test>& tests)
{
    int ret = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<tests.size(); i++)
    {
        string result = apply_algorithm(tests[i].first, algo);
        if(result!=tests[i].second)
            ret-=algo.size();
    }

    ret-=algo.size();

    return ret;
}

algorithm find_algorithm(const vector<test>& tests)
{
    const int goal = max_fitness(tests);

    int best = -10000;

    vector<algorithm> population;

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        population.push_back(random_algoritm());


    int generation = 0;

    int last_print = 0;

    int start = time(NULL);

    pair<algorithm, int> pop[100];

    while(best != goal)
    {
        generation++;

        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
            pop[i]=make_pair(population[i], fitness(population[i], tests));

        sort(pop, pop+100, 
            [](const pair<algorithm, int>& a, const pair<algorithm, int>& b)
            {return a.second > b.second;});

        population[0] = pop[0].first;

        for(int i=1; i<100; i++)
        {
            int chance=rand()%100;

            if(chance>i)
            {
                population[i] = mutate_algoritm(pop[0].first);
            }

            else 
                population[i] = pop[0].first;
        }

        const int first = fitness(population[0], tests);

        if(first>best)
        {
            best=first;
        }
    }

    return population[0];
}

algorithm optimize_algorithm(const vector<test> tests, algorithm algo)
{
    vector<algorithm> population;

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        population.push_back(algo);


    int generation = 0;

    int last_print = 0;


    int best = -algo.size();

    pair<algorithm, int> pop[100];

    while(generation<10000)
    {
        generation++;

        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
            pop[i]=make_pair(population[i], fitness_opt(population[i], tests));

        sort(pop, pop+100, 
            [](const pair<algorithm, int>& a, const pair<algorithm, int>& b)
            {return a.second > b.second;});

        population[0] = pop[0].first;

        for(int i=1; i<100; i++)
        {
            int chance=rand()%100;

            if(chance>i)
            {
                population[i] = mutate_algoritm(pop[0].first);
            }

            else 
                population[i] = pop[0].first;
        }

        const int first = fitness_opt(population[0], tests);

        if(first>best)
            best=first;
    }

    return population[0];
}

int main()
{
    // const vector<test> tests = {{"||*||", "||||"},
    //                             {"||*|||", "||||||"},
    //                             {"||||*||", "||||||||"},
    //                             {"||||*||||", "||||||||||||||||"}};

    // const vector<test> tests = {{"||+||", "||||"},
    //                          {"|+||", "|||"},
    //                          {"|||+|", "||||"}};


    // const vector<test> tests = {{"||-||", ""},
    //                          {"|||-|", "||"},
    //                          {"||-|", "|"}}; 


    const vector<test> tests = {{"||+||", "||||"},
                                {"|||+|", "||||"},
                                {"|+|", "||"}}; 


    int start = time(NULL);

    algorithm un_add = find_algorithm(tests);

    cout<<"Found in "<<time(NULL)-start<<'s'<<endl;

    print_algorithm(un_add);


    un_add = optimize_algorithm(tests, un_add);

    cout<<"Optimized in "<<time(NULL)-start<<'s'<<endl;

    print_algorithm(un_add);

    return 0;
}
```

Он работает правильно, но медленно. Вернее для простого случая (который раскомментирован) он работает быстро (около семи секунд), а для более сложных (трех закомментированных) *очень* долго.

Главный вопрос такой: можно ли сделать его быстрее?

Хочется также услышать критику самого кода, возможно предложений, как сделать его лучше (уверен, он далек от идеала).

---

Мне не нравятся сортировки около 290-ой и 344-ой строк и функция `apply_algorithm` - наверняка есть способы не считать ее в некоторых случаях.

---

Я, наверное, чего-то не понимаю, но замена всех функций типа

```
T mutate_T(const T& t)
{
    ...
    return new_t;
}
```

на

```
void mutate_T(T& t)
{
    ...
    t = new_t;
}
```

Увеличила время исполнения в десять(!) раз.

Получившийся код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::sort;
using std::pair;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

typedef pair<string, string> rule;
typedef vector<rule> algorithm;
typedef pair<string, string> test;


void print_rule(rule r)
{
    cout<<r.first<<" -> "<<r.second<<endl;
}

void print_algorithm(algorithm algo)
{
    cout<<endl;

    for(int i=0; i<algo.size(); i++)
        print_rule(algo[i]);

    cout<<endl;
}


string apply_algorithm(string str, const algorithm& algo, bool verbose=false)
{
    vector<string> prevs;
    int step = 0;

    bool loop=false;


    bool found = false;
    for(int i=0; i<algo.size(); i++)
    {
        if(str.find(algo[i].first)!=-1)
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!found)
        return str;

    while(step<10000 && !loop)
    {
        step++;

        if(str.length()>100)
            break;

        for(int i=0; i<algo.size(); i++)
        {
            if(str.find(algo[i].first) != -1)
            {
                int first = str.find(algo[i].first);
                int len   = (algo[i].first).length();
                str.replace(first, len, algo[i].second);

                if(verbose)
                {
                    cout<<"found '"<<algo[i].first<<"' -> '"<<algo[i].second<<"'"<<endl;
                    cout<<str<<endl;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<prevs.size(); i++)
        {
            if(prevs[i] == str)
            {
                loop = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        prevs.push_back(str);
    }

    return str;
}

void mutate_string(string& str)
{
    int chance = rand()%100;

    if(chance<25)
    {
        char n = (char)(rand()%94+32);
        str.push_back(n);
    }
    else if(chance<50 && str.length()>0)
    {
        str.erase(rand()%str.length(), 1);
    }

    else if(chance<75 && str.length()>0)
    {
        auto index = str.begin()+rand()%str.length();
        str.insert(index, 1, (char)(rand()%94+32));
    }

}

void mutate_rule(rule& r)
{
    int chance = rand()%100;

    if(chance<33)
    {
        mutate_string(r.first);
    }

    else if(chance<66)
    {
        mutate_string(r.second);
    }

    else
    {
        mutate_string(r.first);
        // cout<<left<<endl;
        mutate_string(r.second);
        // cout<<right<<endl;
    }
}

string random_string(const int length)
{
    string ret = "";

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        ret.push_back((char)(rand()%94+32));

    return ret;
}

rule random_rule()
{
    return make_pair(random_string(rand()%5+1),
                     random_string(rand()%5+1));
}

void mutate_algoritm(algorithm& algo)
{
    int chance = rand()%100;

    if(chance<33)
    {
        algo.push_back(random_rule());
        // return algo;
    }

    else if(chance<66 && algo.size() > 1)
    {
        auto index = algo.begin()+rand()%algo.size();
        algo.erase(index);
        // return algo;
    }

    else 
    {
        int index = rand()%algo.size();
        mutate_rule(algo[index]);
        // return algo;
    }
}

algorithm random_algoritm()
{
    int length = rand()%10+1;

    algorithm ret;

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        ret.push_back(random_rule());

    return ret;
}

int max_fitness(const vector<test>& tests)
{
    int length = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<tests.size(); i++)
        length+=tests[i].second.length();

    return length;
}

int difference(const string& a, const string& b)
{
    if(a.length()!=b.length())
        return -abs(a.length()-b.length());

    int ret=0;

    for(int i=0; i<a.length(); i++)
        if(a[i] == b[i])
            ret++;

    return ret;
}

int fitness(const algorithm& algo, const vector<test>& tests)
{
    int ret = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<tests.size(); i++)
    {
        string result = apply_algorithm(tests[i].first, algo);

        ret+=difference(result, tests[i].second);
    }

    return ret;
}                      

int fitness_opt(const algorithm& algo, const vector<test>& tests)
{
    int ret = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<tests.size(); i++)
    {
        string result = apply_algorithm(tests[i].first, algo);
        if(result!=tests[i].second)
            ret-=algo.size();
    }

    ret-=algo.size();

    return ret;
}

algorithm find_algorithm(const vector<test>& tests)
{
    const int goal = max_fitness(tests);

    int best = -10000;

    vector<algorithm> population;

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        population.push_back(random_algoritm());


    int generation = 0;

    int last_print = 0;

    int start = time(NULL);

    pair<algorithm, int> pop[100];

    while(best != goal)
    {
        generation++;

        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
            pop[i]=make_pair(population[i], fitness(population[i], tests));

        sort(pop, pop+100, 
            [](const pair<algorithm, int>& a, const pair<algorithm, int>& b)
            {return a.second > b.second;});

        population[0] = pop[0].first;

        for(int i=1; i<100; i++)
        {
            int chance=rand()%100;

            if(chance>i)
            {
                mutate_algoritm(pop[0].first);
                population[i] = pop[0].first;
            }

            else 
                population[i] = pop[0].first;
        }

        const int first = fitness(population[0], tests);

        if(first>best)
        {
            best=first;
        }
    }

    return population[0];
}

algorithm optimize_algorithm(const vector<test> tests, algorithm algo)
{
    vector<algorithm> population;

    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        population.push_back(algo);


    int generation = 0;

    int last_print = 0;


    int best = -algo.size();

    pair<algorithm, int> pop[100];

    while(generation<10000)
    {
        generation++;

        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
            pop[i]=make_pair(population[i], fitness_opt(population[i], tests));

        sort(pop, pop+100, 
            [](const pair<algorithm, int>& a, const pair<algorithm, int>& b)
            {return a.second > b.second;});

        population[0] = pop[0].first;

        for(int i=1; i<100; i++)
        {
            int chance=rand()%100;

            if(chance>i)
            {
                mutate_algoritm(pop[0].first);
                population[i] = pop[0].first;
            }

            else 
                population[i] = pop[0].first;
        }

        const int first = fitness_opt(population[0], tests);

        if(first>best)
            best=first;
    }

    return population[0];
}

int main()
{
    // const vector<test> tests = {{"||*||", "||||"},
    //                             {"||*|||", "||||||"},
    //                             {"||||*||", "||||||||"},
    //                             {"||||*||||", "||||||||||||||||"}};

    // const vector<test> tests = {{"||+||", "||||"},
    //                          {"|+||", "|||"},
    //                          {"|||+|", "||||"}};


    // const vector<test> tests = {{"||-||", ""},
    //                          {"|||-|", "||"},
    //                          {"||-|", "|"}}; 


    const vector<test> tests = {{"||+||", "||||"},
                                {"|||+|", "||||"},
                                {"|+|", "||"}}; 


    int start = time(NULL);

    algorithm un_add = find_algorithm(tests);

    cout<<"Found in "<<time(NULL)-start<<'s'<<endl;

    print_algorithm(un_add);


    un_add = optimize_algorithm(tests, un_add);

    cout<<"Optimized in "<<time(NULL)-start<<'s'<<endl;

    print_algorithm(un_add);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Для @Voidificator:
Если я правильно понимаю собственный код:

```
    // Суем пары типа 
    // <Алгоритм, фитнес-функция>
    // в массив pop
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        pop[i]=make_pair(population[i], fitness(population[i], tests));

    // Сортируем массив pop по второму значению
    sort(pop, pop+100, 
        [](const pair<algorithm, int>& a, const pair<algorithm, int>& b)
        {return a.second > b.second;});

    population[0] = pop[0].first;

    for(int i=1; i<100; i++)
    {
        int chance=rand()%100;

        if(chance>i)
        {
            // Алгоритм попадает в population
            // либо после мутации
            mutate_algoritm(pop[0].first);
            population[i] = pop[0].first; //
        }

        else 
            population[i] = pop[0].first; // Либо без
    }
```

Comment: Какие места, по-вашему, занимают много времени. Тут код длинный, чтобы быстрее разобраться.

Comment: Как это скомпилировать под линукс 64? Сам нашел: `g++ -o test -std=c++11 -O3 test.cc`

Comment: Забавно, что у меня (VC++ 2015) вышло, что оптимизированный вариант хуже: `Found in 0s

*>n8a -> Dvw
{5q -> _
+ ->

Optimized in 2s

+ ->` А с gcc - тут: https://ideone.com/znDymy (ну, я немного подчистил очевидные вещи).

Comment: Мне кажется, что проблема не в конкретном цикле, а скорее в недетерминированности кода... Код можно причесать; профайлер говорит, что больше всего времени сжирает сравнение строк (вызов `string::compare`) и `new`. От кучи `new` можно избавиться, передавая строки не по значению, а по ссылке - ну на кой у вас вызовы типа `s = func(s);`, в которую `s` передается по значению? только лишние копирования и выделения памяти. Ругается как на съедающие больше всего времени на строки типа `if(str.find(algo[i].first)!=-1)` и `if(prevs[i] == str)`. Но это не разы, а около 15%.

Comment: @Rennorb, с учетом того, что mutate_algoritm теперь принимает ссылку, а не копию, получилось то, что было раньше, но с одним отличием: раньше i-й элемент population получал либо копию pop[0].first, либо однократную мутацию pop[0].first, а теперь, когда к pop[0].first применяются мутации, они там накапливаются. Опять же подозреваю, что это не совсем то, что надо. Как-то мы от оптимизации существующего алгоритма незаметно перешли к его модификации и выяснению, правилен ли он вообще...

Comment: Раз такое дело, советую сначала отладить логику алгоритма (подтянув недостающие знания, если нужно), а потом уже оптимизировать заведомо работающую реализацию. Сейчас она, по моему, работает не так, как должна.

Comment: @Voidificator, очепятался. Вместо `population[i] = pop[0].first;` должно быть `population[i] = pop[i].first;`. Но я правда начинаю запутываться, а алгоритм мало похож (кто бы мог подумать) на оптимальный. Пойду думать над новым. Вопрос, наверное, можно считать закрытым.

Comment: @Voidificator, Первый вариант, в итоге, работает лучше всего.

Answer (score 2):

Навскидку предлагаю такую оптимизацию:

Код вида

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    pop[i]=make_pair(population[i], fitness(population[i], tests));

sort(pop, pop+100,
    [](const pair<algorithm, int>& a, const pair<algorithm, int>& b)
    {return a.second > b.second;});

population[0] = pop[0].first;
...
```

заменить на:

```
pair<algorithm*, int> pop = make_pair(&population[0], fitness(population[0], tests));
for(int i=1; i<100; i++)
{
    int ft = fitness(population[i], tests);
    if(ft > pop.second)
        pop = make_pair(&population[i], ft);
}

algorithm popalg = *pop.first;

population[0] = popalg;
...
```

Ибо, как я понял по коду, вам надо найти алгоритм с максимальным соответствием тестам. Для этого достаточно простого поиска максимума, а полноценная сортировка ни к чему. Кроме того я заменил вектора указателями на них.

А вообще в таких случаях желательно пользоваться профилировщиком. Ибо бывает сложно без измерений оценить, какую выгоду даст то или иное изменение кода.

Comment: Вы не правильно поняли, не могу  сейчас дополнить вопрос объяснением алгоритма, могу только отослать к [статье](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Генетический_алгоритм) на Вики. Доберусь до компьютера, напишу подробнее.

Comment: @Rennorb, я действительно не сталкивался раньше с генетическими алгоритмами, поэтому смотрел не на правильность алгоритмов вообще, а на то, что делает код. А в коде видно, что после того как массив pop отсортирован, далее используется только первый его элемент. То есть, элемент с максимальным fitness. Остальные 99 элементов не используются. Вот я и предложил не делать сортировку как таковую, а просто найти максимум. Если я не прав в своих рассуждениях, то укажите, пожалуйста, в чем.

Comment: @Rennorb, глянул указанную статью, там сортировка действительно нужна, потому что следующее поколение строится на основе части предыдущего. То есть, берется какое-то подмножество, которое обычно содержит > 1 "генотипа". У вас же реально из текущего поколения выбирается только 1 экземпляр, над которым потом выполняются мутации (почему я и предложил такую оптимизацию). Причем, мутации еще и с определенной вероятностью применяются (то есть ряд элементов в следующем поколении - одинаковые). Как с точки зрения теории, это не может быть причиной того, что все долго сходится?

Comment: особи заменяются на мутировавшую первую с вероятность, равной (в процентах) ее номеру после сортировки. Так что некоторые наиболее удачные алгоритмы переходят в следующие поколение. Возможно, действительно стоит убивать худших и заменять их на случайных лучших, которые могут мутировать. Вот только будет ли быстрее? Но попробовать стоит.

Comment: @Voidficator, отписался выше.

Comment: @Rennorb, у меня такое чувство, что вы почему-то полагаете, что алгоритмы в population тоже сортируются, а это не так. В элементах массива pop сидят копии алгоритмов из population, и какие либо манипуляции над pop на population не влияют. Поэтому позиция в массиве population никак не связана с fitness.

Comment: @Voidification, я дополнил вопрос кусочком кода, который, по моему, должен перекладывать алгоритмы из `pop` в `population`.